# Regular Expression to Match Specific "Values" in Isolated Group

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression to test

```
(\&TRUNC)[\(]{1,}(.+)[\)]{1,}
```

And I have this "tester"

```
((((&TRUNC((1800,000 / 510)) * 510) * 920) + (2 * (510 * 700)) + ((&TRUNC((1800,000 / 510)) - 1) * 2 * 510 * 80)) / 1000000) * 85,715
```

My expected value is (inside the personal command "&TRUNC(command)")

```
(1800,000 / 510)
```

I got this value

```
1800,000 / 510)) * 510) * 920) + (2 * (510 * 700)) + ((&TRUNC((1800,000 / 510)) - 1) * 2 * 510 * 80)) / 1000000
```

How can I get only expected value in a separated group?

PS:. The expressions inside the command called for me as "&TRUNC(command)" is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex

```
(\&TRUNC)[\(]{1,}(.+)[\)]{1,}
```

change `.+` to make it not greedy `.+?`

```
(\&TRUNC)[\(]{1,}(.+?)[\)]{1,}
```

You can also simplify a bit

```
&TRUNC\(+(.+?)\)+
```

Comment: This would still give him `&TRUNC((1800,000 / 510))` instead of `(1800,000 / 510)`

Comment: @Jaypal:No, it gives `1800,000 / 510` in the first group.

Comment: Sorry @M42, I don't know .NET. May be you are correct. I saw &TRUNC as a part of RegEx and thought it would end up matching it as well.

Answer (score 0):

With SED, you can use back reference to match the text you are looking for -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat input_file 
((((&TRUNC((1800,000 / 510)) * 510) * 920) + (2 * (510 * 700)) + ((&TRUNC((1800,000 / 510)) - 1) * 2 * 510 * 80)) / 1000000) * 85,715

[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed 's/.[^(&TRUNC)]*(*\&TRUNC((\(.[^*)]*\)))* \* .*/\1/' input_file
1800,000 / 510
```

Sorry, I dont know .NET but how about this one -

```
([\(]{1}[0-9,/ ]+[\)]{1})
```

Comment: Jaypal I am using .Net to verify the regular expression, I tested your expression but I don't got success.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know .NET. But I have updated the solution. Don't know if that would work though.